# Setting the color of the nodes in d3

Tags: d3.js, canvas

I am playing with a D3 example [Force Dragging](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048) on bl.ocks.org.

I am loading the nodes from JSON file, but I am not able to figure out on how to set the color of the nodes (initially any color but ideally I would like to provide the color of the nodes in the JSON).

**Code : (copied from bl.ocks.org)**

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("../data/prc_network.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  d3.select(canvas)
      .call(d3.drag()
          .container(canvas)
          .subject(dragsubject)
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  function ticked() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.beginPath();
    graph.links.forEach(drawLink);
    context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode);
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    context.stroke();
  }

  function dragsubject() {
    return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
  }
});

function dragstarted() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.subject.x;
  d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.subject.y;
}

function dragged() {
  d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.x;
  d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);

}

function drawLink(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
  context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
}

function drawNode(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}

</script>
```

Comment: You linked the wrong bl.ocks. Do you want the SVG version or the Canvas version?

Comment: Thanks, updated the link. I am looking for the Canvas version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start a new path each time you want to color one node - as each path has a set styling. To do this we need to move all the node drawing portions to the `drawNode` function as opposed to the `tick` function so that we can style each node individually:

```
function drawNode(d) {
  context.beginPath(); 
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = d.color // or some other property that has a valid color
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.stroke();
}
```

We can also use a scale to take some property and convert it to a color:

```
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20);

function drawNode(d) {
  context.beginPath(); 
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = colors(d.property);
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.stroke();
}
```

Here's a [block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/6eb57b49b986d4c55f42c96a618ba442) using the base example (with the base data) coloring for node group.